# Pyspark task completion callback from task context

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to send http POSTs using spark. The basic psuedocode is as follows:

```
def udf(task_id): 
  http_post(task_id)

task_ids = range(100)
rdd = sc.parallelize(task_ids)
rdd.map(udf)
```

The above code is too slow as it waits for each post to return. To solve this problem I thought it would be good to use a threadpool and queue within the UDF. The threads pull items off the queue and the when all of them are done the spark task is done.

```
class Sender()
    def  __init__():
        self.q = Queue()
        self.max_threads = 5

    def post(task_id):
       self.q.put(task_id)
       init_thread()

    def work():
       data = q.get()
       post_request(data)

    def init_thread():
        if len(self.thread) < self.max_threads:
            t = Thread(target=work,args=())
            self.threads.append(t)

def udf(task_id, sender): 
  sender.post(task_id)


sender = Sender()
task_ids = range(100)
rdd = sc.parallelize(task_ids)
rdd.map(lambda x: udf(x,sender))
```

The problem is that i want the spark task to wait until all the threads complete and the queue is empty. The ideal solution for this would be a callback so that when the spark task is done the callback is called and the callback does a `.join()` on the queue. Unfortunately it seems there is no way to do a callback within a task context in pyspark.

Is there a alternative way to do a task completion callback or wait for the queue to complete?